# Java program won't run, I've no clue what's wrong

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I've been trying to figure out why this Java program I am trying to run won't do it. It's not finished yet, but I'm just trying to make sure I got all the GUI aspects the way I want them to be. Netbeans wont even tell me whats going on no matter what I do, but it will run other programs just fine.

```
package TheGameCorner;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HeartAndSoul extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
 Random rand = new Random();

 int bombs = 13; 
 int newBombCheck = 0;
 int bombX, bombY;
 String bombCarrier;
 String bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen;
 int gameOver = 0;
 int scoreVal = 0, colOneVal = 0, colTwoVal = 0, colThreeVal = 0, colFourVal = 0, colFiveVal = 0, rowOneVal = 0, rowTwoVal = 0, rowThreeVal = 0, rowFourVal = 0, rowFiveVal = 0;
 String oneOneVal = "oneOne", oneTwoVal = "oneTwo", oneThreeVal = "oneThree", oneFourVal = "oneFour", oneFiveVal = "oneFive";
 String twoOneVal = "twoOne", twoTwoVal = "twoTwo", twoThreeVal = "twoThree", twoFourVal = "twoFour", twoFiveVal = "twoFive";
 String threeOneVal = "threeOne", threeTwoVal = "threeTwo", threeThreeVal = "threeThree", threeFourVal = "threeFour", threeFiveVal = "threeFive";
 String fourOneVal = "fourOne", fourTwoVal = "fourTwo", fourThreeVal = "fourThree", fourFourVal = "fourFour", fourFiveVal = "fourFive";
 String fiveOneVal = "fiveOne", fiveTwoVal = "fiveTwo", fiveThreeVal = "fiveThree", fiveFourVal = "fiveFour", fiveFiveVal = "fiveFive";

 public HeartAndSoul(String title) 
 {
  super(title);

  bOne = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen); //<editor-fold>
  bTwo = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bThree = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bFour = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bFive = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bSix = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bSeven = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bEight = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bNine = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bTen = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bEleven = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bTwelve = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen);
  bThirteen = BombGen(bOne, bTwo, bThree, bFour, bFive, bSix, bSeven, bEight, bNine, bTen, bEleven, bTwelve, bThirteen); //</editor-fold>

  oneOneVal = SetBomb(oneOneVal); //<editor-fold>
  oneTwoVal = SetBomb(oneTwoVal);
  oneThreeVal = SetBomb(oneThreeVal);
  oneFourVal = SetBomb(oneFourVal);
  oneFiveVal = SetBomb(oneFiveVal);

  twoOneVal = SetBomb(twoOneVal);
  twoTwoVal = SetBomb(twoTwoVal);
  twoThreeVal = SetBomb(twoThreeVal);
  twoFourVal = SetBomb(twoFourVal);
  twoFiveVal = SetBomb(twoFiveVal);

  threeOneVal = SetBomb(threeOneVal);
  threeTwoVal = SetBomb(threeTwoVal);
  threeThreeVal = SetBomb(threeThreeVal);
  threeFourVal = SetBomb(threeFourVal);
  threeFiveVal = SetBomb(threeFiveVal);

  fourOneVal = SetBomb(fourOneVal);
  fourTwoVal = SetBomb(fourTwoVal);
  fourThreeVal = SetBomb(fourThreeVal);
  fourFourVal = SetBomb(fourFourVal);
  fourFiveVal = SetBomb(fourFiveVal);

  fiveOneVal = SetBomb(fiveOneVal);
  fiveTwoVal = SetBomb(fiveTwoVal);
  fiveThreeVal = SetBomb(fiveThreeVal);
  fiveFourVal = SetBomb(fiveFourVal);
  fiveFiveVal = SetBomb(fiveFiveVal); //</editor-fold>

  if (oneOneVal.equals("b")) //<editor-fold>
  {
   rowOneVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colOneVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (oneTwoVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowOneVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colTwoVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (oneThreeVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowOneVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colThreeVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (oneFourVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowOneVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFourVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (oneFiveVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowOneVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFiveVal=colOneVal+1;
  }

  if (twoOneVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowTwoVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colOneVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (twoTwoVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowTwoVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colTwoVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (twoThreeVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowTwoVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colThreeVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (twoFourVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowTwoVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFourVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (twoFiveVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowTwoVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFiveVal=colOneVal+1;
  }

  if (threeOneVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowThreeVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colOneVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (threeTwoVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowThreeVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colTwoVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (threeThreeVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowThreeVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colThreeVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (threeFourVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowThreeVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFourVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (threeFiveVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowThreeVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFiveVal=colOneVal+1;
  }

  if (fourOneVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFourVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colOneVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (fourTwoVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFourVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colTwoVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (fourThreeVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFourVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colThreeVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (fourFourVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFourVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFourVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (fourFiveVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFourVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFiveVal=colOneVal+1;
  }

  if (fiveOneVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFiveVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colOneVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (fiveTwoVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFiveVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colTwoVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (fiveThreeVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFiveVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colThreeVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (fiveFourVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFiveVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFourVal=colOneVal+1;
  }
  if (fiveFiveVal.equals("b"))
  {
   rowFiveVal=rowOneVal+1;
   colFiveVal=colOneVal+1;
  } //</editor-fold>

  JPanel refRow = new JPanel(), oneRow = new JPanel(), twoRow = new JPanel(), threeRow = new JPanel(), fourRow = new JPanel(), fiveRow = new JPanel(), infoRow = new JPanel(); //<editor-fold>

  JTextField colOne = new JTextField(1), colTwo = new JTextField(1), colThree = new JTextField(1), colFour = new JTextField(1), colFive = new JTextField(1), rowOne = new JTextField(1), rowTwo = new JTextField(1), rowThree = new JTextField(1), rowFour = new JTextField(1), rowFive = new JTextField(1), score = new JTextField(9);

  colOne.setEditable(false); colTwo.setEditable(false); colThree.setEditable(false); colFour.setEditable(false); colFive.setEditable(false); rowOne.setEditable(false); rowTwo.setEditable(false); rowThree.setEditable(false); rowFour.setEditable(false); rowFive.setEditable(false); score.setEditable(false);

  JButton oneOne = new JButton(""), oneTwo = new JButton(""), oneThree = new JButton(""), oneFour = new JButton(""), oneFive = new JButton(""), twoOne = new JButton(""), twoTwo = new JButton(""), twoThree = new JButton(""), twoFour = new JButton(""), twoFive = new JButton(""), threeOne = new JButton(""), threeTwo = new JButton(""), threeThree = new JButton(""), threeFour = new JButton(""), threeFive = new JButton(""), fourOne = new JButton(""), fourTwo = new JButton(""), fourThree = new JButton(""), fourFour = new JButton(""), fourFive = new JButton(""), fiveOne = new JButton(""), fiveTwo = new JButton(""), fiveThree = new JButton(""), fiveFour = new JButton(""), fiveFive = new JButton("");

  oneOne.setSize(20,20); oneTwo.setSize(20,20); oneThree.setSize(20,20); oneFour.setSize(20,20); oneFive.setSize(20,20); twoOne.setSize(20,20); twoTwo.setSize(20,20); twoThree.setSize(20,20); twoFour.setSize(20,20); twoFive.setSize(20,20); threeOne.setSize(20,20); threeTwo.setSize(20,20); threeThree.setSize(20,20); threeFour.setSize(20,20); threeFive.setSize(20,20); fourOne.setSize(20,20); fourTwo.setSize(20,20); fourThree.setSize(20,20); fourFour.setSize(20,20); fourFive.setSize(20,20); fiveOne.setSize(20,20); fiveTwo.setSize(20,20); fiveThree.setSize(20,20); fiveFour.setSize(20,20); fiveFive.setSize(20,20);

  oneOne.setActionCommand(oneOneVal); oneTwo.setActionCommand(oneTwoVal); oneThree.setActionCommand(oneThreeVal); oneFour.setActionCommand(oneFourVal); oneFive.setActionCommand(oneFiveVal); twoOne.setActionCommand(twoOneVal); twoTwo.setActionCommand(twoTwoVal); twoThree.setActionCommand(twoThreeVal); twoFour.setActionCommand(twoFourVal); twoFive.setActionCommand(twoFiveVal); threeOne.setActionCommand(threeOneVal); threeTwo.setActionCommand(threeTwoVal); threeThree.setActionCommand(threeThreeVal); threeFour.setActionCommand(threeFourVal); threeFive.setActionCommand(threeFiveVal); fourOne.setActionCommand(fourOneVal); fourTwo.setActionCommand(fourTwoVal); fourThree.setActionCommand(fourThreeVal); fourFour.setActionCommand(fourFourVal); fourFive.setActionCommand(fourFiveVal); fiveOne.setActionCommand(fiveOneVal); fiveTwo.setActionCommand(fiveTwoVal); fiveThree.setActionCommand(fiveThreeVal); fiveFour.setActionCommand(fiveFourVal); fiveFive.setActionCommand(fiveFiveVal);

  oneOne.addActionListener(this); oneTwo.addActionListener(this); oneThree.addActionListener(this); oneFour.addActionListener(this); oneFive.addActionListener(this); twoOne.addActionListener(this); twoTwo.addActionListener(this); twoThree.addActionListener(this); twoFour.addActionListener(this); twoFive.addActionListener(this); threeOne.addActionListener(this); threeTwo.addActionListener(this); threeThree.addActionListener(this); threeFour.addActionListener(this); threeFive.addActionListener(this); fourOne.addActionListener(this); fourTwo.addActionListener(this); fourThree.addActionListener(this); fourFour.addActionListener(this); fourFive.addActionListener(this); fiveOne.addActionListener(this); fiveTwo.addActionListener(this); fiveThree.addActionListener(this); fiveFour.addActionListener(this); fiveFive.addActionListener(this);

  JLabel scoreText = new JLabel("Score:");

  refRow.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
  oneRow.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
  twoRow.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
  threeRow.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
  fourRow.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
  fiveRow.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
  infoRow.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

  refRow.setSize(150,40);
  oneRow.setSize(150,40);
  twoRow.setSize(150,40);
  threeRow.setSize(150,40);
  fourRow.setSize(150,40);
  fiveRow.setSize(150,40);
  infoRow.setSize(150,40);

  refRow.add(colOne);
  refRow.add(colTwo);
  refRow.add(colThree);
  refRow.add(colFour);
  refRow.add(colFive);

  oneRow.add(oneOne);
  oneRow.add(oneTwo);
  oneRow.add(oneThree);
  oneRow.add(oneFour);
  oneRow.add(oneFive);
  oneRow.add(rowOne);

  twoRow.add(twoOne);
  twoRow.add(twoTwo);
  twoRow.add(twoThree);
  twoRow.add(twoFour);
  twoRow.add(twoFive);
  twoRow.add(rowTwo);

  threeRow.add(threeOne);
  threeRow.add(threeTwo);
  threeRow.add(threeThree);
  threeRow.add(threeFour);
  threeRow.add(threeFive);
  threeRow.add(rowThree);

  fourRow.add(fourOne);
  fourRow.add(fourTwo);
  fourRow.add(fourThree);
  fourRow.add(fourFour);
  fourRow.add(fourFive);
  fourRow.add(rowFour);

  fiveRow.add(fiveOne);
  fiveRow.add(fiveTwo);
  fiveRow.add(fiveThree);
  fiveRow.add(fiveFour);
  fiveRow.add(fiveFive);
  fiveRow.add(rowFive);

  infoRow.add(scoreText);
  infoRow.add(score); //</editor-fold>

  setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  add(refRow);
  add(oneRow);
  add(twoRow);
  add(threeRow);
  add(fourRow);
  add(fiveRow);
  add(infoRow);

  colOne.setText(colOneVal+"");
  colTwo.setText(colTwoVal+"");
  colThree.setText(colThreeVal+"");
  colFour.setText(colFourVal+"");
  colFive.setText(colFiveVal+"");
  rowOne.setText(rowOneVal+"");
  rowTwo.setText(rowTwoVal+"");
  rowThree.setText(rowThreeVal+"");
  rowFour.setText(rowFourVal+"");
  rowFive.setText(rowFiveVal+"");
  score.setText(scoreVal+"");

  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)  
 {
  //more code will go here, not done yet
  repaint(); 
 }

 private String BombGen(String bone, String btwo, String bthree, String bfour, String bfive, String bsix, String bseven, String beight, String bnine, String bten, String beleven, String btwelve, String bthirteen)
 {
  newBombCheck = 0;

  while (newBombCheck == 0)
  {
   bombX = rand.nextInt(5)+1;
   bombY = rand.nextInt(5)+1;

   if (bombX == 1)
    bombCarrier="one";
   if (bombX == 2)
    bombCarrier="two";
   if (bombX == 3)
    bombCarrier="three";
   if (bombX == 4)
    bombCarrier="four";
   if (bombX == 5)
    bombCarrier="five";

   if (bombY == 1)
    bombCarrier.concat("One");
   if (bombY == 2)
    bombCarrier.concat("Two");
   if (bombY == 3)
    bombCarrier.concat("Three");
   if (bombY == 4)
    bombCarrier.concat("Four");
   if (bombY == 5)
    bombCarrier.concat("Five");

   if (!bombCarrier.equals(bone) && !bombCarrier.equals(btwo) && !bombCarrier.equals(bthree) && !bombCarrier.equals(bfour) && !bombCarrier.equals(bfive) && !bombCarrier.equals(bsix) && !bombCarrier.equals(bseven) && !bombCarrier.equals(beight) && !bombCarrier.equals(bnine) && !bombCarrier.equals(bten) && !bombCarrier.equals(beleven) && !bombCarrier.equals(btwelve) && !bombCarrier.equals(bthirteen))
    newBombCheck = 1;
  } 
  return bombCarrier;
 }

 private String SetBomb(String suspect)
 {
  if (suspect.equals(bOne) || suspect.equals(bTwo) || suspect.equals(bThree) || suspect.equals(bFour) || suspect.equals(bFive) || suspect.equals(bSix) || suspect.equals(bSeven) || suspect.equals(bEight) || suspect.equals(bNine) || suspect.equals(bTen) || suspect.equals(bEleven) || suspect.equals(bTwelve) || suspect.equals(bThirteen))
   suspect = "b";
  return suspect;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  HeartAndSoul echo = new HeartAndSoul("The Game Corner") ;
  echo.setSize(200,300);     
  echo.setVisible(true);      
 }
}
```

Sorry it's so long, but I wanted to put the entire thing up because I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've tried being more specific with adding the action listener, I've tried adding Override annotation, but Netbeans refuses to get further than starting the execution of the program.

Comment: Can you tell us what the program is supposed to do?

Comment: @Bohemian: *More* code?!

Comment: Compile and try to run the program from command line. If it doesn't compile or run, post the stack trace in your question.

Comment: Is this a MineSweeper game? The first thing I'd do is change it to use a 2-dimensional array instead of a separate variable for each box. From there, you can write a generic method that takes the clicked component and updates its label accordingly. That'll be a lot more concise, and easier to debug.

Comment: So, you can see the frame? What is your expected behavior?

Comment: @aix - of course (</sarcasm>)

Comment: Kudos to anyone who actually read through all that code

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I actually find those waves of nearly-identical code strangely soothing... ;)

Comment: can we close this question and use only the code starting a 500 bounty for guessing what it supposed to do?

Comment: @aix - I actually clicked on the code after your response to me - holy moly, that's something else :)

Comment: if you look up the game corner from the Pokemon Heart Gld Soul Silver games on you tube, you will see what I'm trying to build. I'm not that familiar with arrays, so I'll look into that, and I'll also try the command prompt run when I get home. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
  while (newBombCheck == 0)
```

Inside this loop put `System.out.println(bombCarrier);` and check whether the values are as you would expect them to be. Whatever the values are, your code never hits the `if` statement in this loop and thus `newBombCheck` is never set to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used it and I found out why it wasn't working. The concat part wasn't working, so now I just have to figure out why.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, I forgot to set bombCarrier equal to it's concat. Wow, that was a lot of stress for a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if (!bombCarrier.equals(bone) && !bombCarrier.equals(btwo) && !bombCarrier.equals(bthree) && !bombCarrier.equals(bfour) && !bombCarrier.equals(bfive) && !bombCarrier.equals(bsix) && !bombCarrier.equals(bseven) && !bombCarrier.equals(beight) && !bombCarrier.equals(bnine) && !bombCarrier.equals(bten) && !bombCarrier.equals(beleven) && !bombCarrier.equals(btwelve) && !bombCarrier.equals(bthirteen))
newBombCheck = 1;
```

This if is never entered, thus newBombCheck is never set to 1, thus the loop runs forever.

You should think a bit stuff over. Also doing SO MUCH in a constructor is just wrong, to me.
This code is going to be a nightmare to maintain, you might want to rename things a bit, and add comments to make is clear what you want to achieve and why may be

Cheers, Eugene.

Comment: Thanks I appriciate the help, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Are you saying that it is never true? If so, then I think I know how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I took you advice and I woved a lot of things out of the contructor. It has help quite a bit so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is in an infinite loop in the `BombGen` method. `newBombCheck` is always 0. What you should do is run in the debugger, and then pause the app. It will always stop in your loop, which should tell you something is wrong.

Comment: Its only an infinite loop if it doesn't genereate a new bomb when it runs, because it chacks to see that it is different from all of them:
    if (!bombCarrier.equals(bone) && !bombCarrier.equals(btwo) && !bombCarrier.equals(bthree) && !bombCarrier.equals(bfour) && !bombCarrier.equals(bfive) && !bombCarrier.equals(bsix) && !bombCarrier.equals(bseven) && !bombCarrier.equals(beight) && !bombCarrier.equals(bnine) && !bombCarrier.equals(bten) && !bombCarrier.equals(beleven) && !bombCarrier.equals(btwelve) && !bombCarrier.equals(bthirteen))
         newBombCheck = 1;

Comment: I ran the code you posted and it never terminates, and so your app never shows. You need to rethink your if statement here, it isn't doing what you think it is. Use the debugger.

Comment: I used the debugger, but abolutely nothing happened, which is why I posted this

Answer (score 0):

```
 bombX = rand.nextInt(5)+1;
   bombY = rand.nextInt(5)+1;

   if (bombX == 1)
    bombCarrier="one";
   if (bombX == 2)
    bombCarrier="two";
   if (bombX == 3)
    bombCarrier="three";
   if (bombX == 4)
    bombCarrier="four";
   if (bombX == 5)
    bombCarrier="five";

   if (bombY == 1)
    bombCarrier.concat("One");
   if (bombY == 2)
    bombCarrier.concat("Two");
   if (bombY == 3)
    bombCarrier.concat("Three");
   if (bombY == 4)
    bombCarrier.concat("Four");
   if (bombY == 5)
    bombCarrier.concat("Five");
```

I think You tried to scale it from 5*5 to 13*13, but forgot to add bombX=6...13 and for bombY too. that's why it stuck after bombGen6.
and then your condition is never true and keep generating ran numbers b/w 1-5.

Comment: No, I want 13 different bombs on a 5X5 grid, that generates the x and y coordinates of the bombs.